# Trix editor not working properly with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix

I have a Rails 6 application that uses bootstrap-form and the "trix" gem. I can't use ActionText because it requires webpacker which I can't use for a number of reasons.

In my form I do this:

```
<%= f.rich_text_area :content, layout: :vertical, rows: 20, required: true %>
```

But the editor is broken, see below:

[image: broken trix editor]

It gets even worse if I try to drop in an image:

[image: trix editor broken file upload]

There are no errors in the logs or console, I am not overriding any of the CSS or JS.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am using `trix` as a separated gem on my rails 5 project as well, and my syntax is different with you `f.input :content, as: :trix_editor, ...`. I googled you code and look like `f.rich_text_area` is a helper for ActionText editor (which you are trying not to use)

Comment: And did you add the JavaScript + CSS assets of Trix gem correctly?

Comment: Assets are installed correctly. Using f.input => undefined method `input' for #<BootstrapForm::FormBuilder>

Comment: you are using bootstrap_form gem?

Comment: Yes I am, their github says it's supposed to work

Comment: Do you have `has_rich_text :your_field` in your model? Action Text Overview guide [mentions it](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html#examples).

Comment: Adam, I've tried with and without it and it makes no difference - the editor still misbehaves.

Comment: It seems that your trix editor input is not resizing correctly. I would check if trix-editor element has `max-height` style set or `height` overridden by some other stylesheet or script.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you figured this out already but if not I had the same problem and discovered that the Bootstrap form-control class was restricting the height of the Trix Editor. I added the following code to my Application.scss file and now it works like you would expect:

```css
trix-editor {
    height:auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
progress {
  display: none;
}
```

You can add into you css file may resolve you image progess bar issue.